# Ajax function not triggering

Tags: ajax

Why my 'Ajax' function is not triggering when changing the 'state' please help. even the 'console' is not showing the value. When i comment Ajax function I am getting the stateID in console

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on("change", "#state", function(){
             var stateID = $(this).val();
              console.log('value of StateID'+stateID);
              $.ajax({
                   url:"user/getCity"
                   async: false,
                   type: "POST", 
                   data: {stateID,stateID},
                   dataType: "html",
                   success: function(data) {
                        //$('#city').html(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
               })
         });
    });
```

Comment: What is "#state"? Is an input var?

Comment: Anyway there is an error: "...data: {stateID,stateID}..." is not correct. Must be like this: data: { stateID: stateID }

Comment: Thanks Roberto, but still its not working. I am newbie in Jquery Ajax.. Please help

Comment: No ""#state" is a drop down menu

Comment: Please, post all page code and remember that if your dropdown is generated "runtime" while building the page, you have to use live("change")